# Android Studio RC 1 Gradle build wont compile after update

Tags: build, gradle, android-studio, libraries, aar

After an intensive search on the internet, I couldn't find any answer to my problem. After I upgraded android studio from beta to rc1, the gradle build script stopped working with the following error:

```
Error:String index out of range: -1
```

My build script is as follows:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

repositories {
    jcenter()
    flatDir {
        dirs 'libs'
    }
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 21
    buildToolsVersion '21.1.1'

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId 'myappidhere'
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 21
        versionCode 1
        versionName '1.0'
    }
    lintOptions {
        abortOnError false
    }

    android {
        sourceSets {
            main {
                manifest.srcFile 'src/main/AndroidManifest.xml'
                java.srcDirs = ['src/main/java', 'src/main/java-gen']
                res.srcDirs = ['src/main/res']
            }
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.0.2'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:21.0.2'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:21.0.0'
    compile 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:6.0.0'
    compile 'com.jakewharton.timber:timber:2.5.0'
    compile 'de.greenrobot:greendao:1.3.7'
    compile 'com.rengwuxian.materialedittext:library:1.5.0'
    //local libs
    compile(name: 'utilsaaa1', ext: 'aar')
    compile(name: 'pixlui_1_0_5_fork', ext: 'aar')
    compile project(':Secure_preferences_lib')
}
```

After reading the gradle log error, the problematic lines are the following:

```
 compile(name: 'utilsaaa1', ext: 'aar')
        compile(name: 'pixlui_1_0_5_fork', ext: 'aar')
```

Both files are inside folder libs.
I have no idea how to fix this so any help would be appreciated.

EDIT1: idea.log

```
Caused by: org.gradle.api.IllegalDependencyNotation: Supplied String module notation 'utilsaaa1' is invalid. Example notations: 'org.gradle:gradle-core:2.2', 'org.mockito:mockito-core:1.9.5:javadoc'.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change:

```
 compile(name: 'utilsaaa1', ext: 'aar')
```

To:

```
 compile 'myappidhere:utilsaaa1:1.0@aar'
```